# Determine the heading of a polygon by the longest side

Tags: polygon, direction, angles, default-value, heading

I want to add direction arrows of polygons based on first drawn points of a polygon in QGIS. Heading of a polygon should be also added to a column `heading` of polygons layer. The solution should be an expression so it would automatically add values when a polygon is created.

I have tried `main_angle(@geometry)` but it only returns heading angle only of 0-180 deg, but I need 0-360 deg. format.

As shown on the pic. below, heading of lines 1-2 lines should be calculated.
[image]

Comment: What software is this? Does `main_angle` return a value from -180 to +180? In which case you need the value "mod 360" to get (-180,180) to map to  (180-360,0-180). Is there an arithmetic "modulo" function in whatever application this is?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or drawing showing what you want to calculate?

Comment: Added screenshot and updated question.